# How to write a Groovy script to truncate a string at 60 characters?

Tags: java, groovy

How do I truncate a string at 60 characters?

Answer (score 1):

> How to write a Groovy script to truncate a string at 60 characters?

You could do something like this:

```
if(!args) {
    System.err.println 'A command line argument is required'
    System.exit(-1)
}

arg = args[0]

if(arg.size() > 60) {
   arg = arg[0..59]
}

println arg
```

Output:

```
demo $ groovy truncate.groovy                                                                               
A command line argument is required
demo $ 
demo $ groovy truncate.groovy abcdef                                                                        
abcdef
demo $ 
demo $ groovy truncate.groovy abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefgh
```

Comment: Why not just `theString.take(60)` ?

Comment: @ou_ryperd I think `theString.take(60)` is a great solution.  Well done!